# How can I have my machine locked, but it appears unlocked, ie you see desktop and apps?

Tags: macos, screensaver

At work we troll eachother when we find unlocked computers. I want to troll the trolls by having them think I forgot to lock my computer, so it must appear unlocked, but be as safe as any other normally locked screensaver. Ofc I will have to hide anything sensitive myself before it makes screenshots or however it will work.

Is there such a thing somewhere?

Comment: An image screensaver with the only image as your desktop?

Comment: I have 3 monitors though

Answer (score 1):

Use an image screen saver. Since you have 3 monitors, make sure the image resolution = (width of all 3 monitors) x height